# Java generics - compilation error

Tags: java, generics

Why it doesn't work ?

```
class W<A extends Number>
   {
      public void create(A value)
      {

      }
   }

   public void calculate(W<? extends Number> w)
   {
      Integer v = 5;
      w.create(v); // Compilation error
   }
```

Could somebody explain what is wrong with that code and how to fix it?

Compilation error : "create (capture) in W cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer)"

Comment: Post the error message please.

Comment: create (capture<? extends java.lang.Number>) in W cannot be applied to (java.lang.Integer)

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include relevant information.

Comment: oh sorry, I interpreted wrong! please add more info

Comment: It's not really clear what you're trying to do. Both `A` and `? extends Number` are not necessarily `Integer`, so you can't expect `v` to be valid input. Maybe you mean `W<? super Integer>`?

Comment: See also [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Answer (score 2):

You have a common misconception about wildcards in generics. You think that `?` means you can pass any type (as long as it extends `Number`), but you cannot.

`? extends Number` does not mean that you can pass any type that extends `Number`. It means "a specific, but unknown type that extends `Number`". Since the exact type is unknown to the compiler, it cannot allow you to use `Integer` - the compiler at that point simply has not enough information to check if it is type-safe. (It doesn't know if the actual type of the `W` that you pass to the method is `Integer` or some other type that extends `Number`).

This is exactly the same reason as why you cannot add anything to a `List<?>`, for example, which is a question that people often ask.

Comment: When it is asked so often, I am wondering why you are not duplicating this question to one of these many existing ones :-)

Answer (score 1):

This follows straight from the core generics principle. When you use `? extends SomeType`, you cannot *pass*/*consume* anything *into* the reference, as this might violate type safety guarantee provided by the Generics when retrieving these items. One would then be able to do -

```
List<Long> longs = Arrays.asList(5L, 10L, 20L);
List<? extends Number> numbers = longs;


// Trouble!
numbers.add(10.5);
```

See one of my blog posts [here](http://www.codesod.com/2017/02/subtyping-in-java-generics.html) for details on how subtyping works with Generics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bounderies in the **create** method:

```
public <T extends Number> void  create(final T value) {

 }
```

Example:

```
class W<A extends Number> {
    public <T extends Number> void  create(final T value) {

    }

    public void calculate(final W<? extends Number> w) {
        final Integer v = 5;
        w.create(v); // Compilation error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare what kind of W you're using before you use it

```
public void calculate(W<? extends Number> w) {
    Integer v = 5;
    new W<Integer>().create(v);
}
```

or, you can change the create method to accept any number

```
public void create(Number value) {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Both objects should extend Number, but that does NOT mean these objects cannot be siblings:

- ClassA extends Number {..}
- ClassB extends Number {..}

ClassA cannot be casted to ClassB, and this is what **could** happen in your code. It can be both ClassA but your compiler cannot be sure of that as it could be ClassB or any other class extending Number, so it gives a compile error.

Comment: This doesn't make sense, he's not extending java.lang.Number, he's declaring that to be the type of the wildcard 'A' in W.java file

Comment: Yes, which should extend Number. The generic I shown as a class

Comment: I can see what you meant, but I guess it probably wouldn't be clear to someone like OP who doesn't understand how Generics function in the first place:)